# How to detect whether browser supports HTTP pipeline or not with JavaScript?

Tags: http, pipeline

While reading http://www.blaze.io/mobile/http-pipelining-big-in-mobile/, I'm wondering whether it is possible to detect whether specific browser supports HTTP pipeline or not.

Since there are few browsers supporting HTTP pipelines for the time being, we can just use browser-detection. But, I prefer to do it with feature-detection so it is future-compatible.

It would be helpful since then we can adjust whether to use domain sharding or just leverage pipelines.